# Testng not working

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I'm kinda new to automation testing and I reached a problem. I'm currently practicing **Page object model**. I wrote a script for a log in page for a website and when I finished, I tried running testng but when I tried it gave me an error saying:

> Error: Main parameters are required ("file1 [file2 file3...]") Usage:
>    [options] file1 [file2 file3...]   Options:
>       -d
>          The directory where the file(s) will be created
>          Default: .

Here is my script

```
@Test
public void VerfiyLoginWordpress()
{

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.com%2F");

LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);

login.TypeUserName();
login.typePassword();
login.RememberMe();
login.clickOnLoginButton();

 driver.quit();
```

Can someone please help out a noob? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you need to do here:

1. You have to specify the location of the chrome driver in the beginning:

   `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\your_driver_folder\\chrome.exe");`
2. Never use `driver.manage().window().maximize();` to handle Chrome browser, rather handle it through ChromeOptions class.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Dev, it worked and ChromeOptions?? I have been using driver.mange().window().maximize(); for a while now and it never gave me a issue. I am just curious on why would you prefer ChromeOptions?

Comment: @PaulOrszulak If you keep updating your drivers and Chrome browsers as per the latest releases you are bound to hit the issue with Chrome. So I just simply want you to be prepared & cautious. :) Can you Accept the answer as a Solution now?